# Allocate object on heap or stack

Tags: c++

I have a two class car and person. car has a pointer of person type.
then there is this function

```
void f() {
vector<Car> v;
v.push_back(Car("ABC123", new Person("Johan")));
v.push_back(Car("XYZ789", new Person("Bo")));
v.push_back(Car("DEF456", new Person("Anna")));
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<Car>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

F has memory leak.
If i want don't want to allocate memory for obj on the heap should i replace the pointer to person in car with a person p variable?

will the following call in f() work,

```
v.push_back(Car("ABC123", Person("Johan")));
```

or will F still have problems?

Comment: Yes, no reason to use pointers from what you've shown.

Comment: You need to be *very* clear when working with pointers like this. In this case, if the `Car` object *owned* the pointer, it could `delete` in the destructor. Otherwise you either need to change and not use pointers or clean them up separately. Smart pointers are also something you could look at.

Comment: Whether it works or not depends on your constructor definition for `Car`. `new Person("Johan")` passes a pointer to the constructor while `Person("Johan")` passes a temporary object.

Comment: `copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<Car>(cout, "\n"));` is very old-school. May I suggest the modern `for (auto&& x : v) std::cout << x << '\n';` solution?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends a bit on what you want to do. For your test code yes, you could just copy Person values into the (properly changed) car class.

But you seem to have relations between objects, like in a data base. So, could a person in a later stage of your prog have houses, be married etc.?  Then there should only be one instance of each individual, and you need to ref or point to them. But then you would "create" those persons outside f() anywhere, maybe in bed(). ;-)

Comment: Yes this is what i want to do. 
Should i continue using pointers for person?
a person won't be able to own two cars then. 
if i write a destructor for car that deletes the person pointer.

Comment: Hell, no, that destructor shouldn't do that! Unless the person forgot to exit the car before it got into the scrap press! The car doesn't own the person. The person is created in bed() and may be destroyed in car.crash() or in bury_alive(). No, seriously: Persons have lifes of their own in the program. A person can also own more than one car (although they shouldn't, because of the carbon footprint) -- you can assign a person's address to as many cars as have space in your world simulation. But you need to traverse all items which hold references/pointers to persons when one dies (seriously).

Comment: So you may want to introduce something like a citizen's register as we have in Germany. (We are very proud of our book-keeping.) That could be a static vector in the Person class itself; the Person() constructor adds "this" there, and the destructor should remove "this", or you create a zombie army. I know you don't have a register in the US; maybe you should have at least a map<SSID, Person*>? But then you have to deal with the illegals without an SSID; what a mess.